# Returning valuse from async / await function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The template below is an object of class Template -
I am trying to return the template objeect from the async function and from what I have seen what I have below should work but it doeesn't. If I put my console.log statements within the functionit works but I can't get it to return the templateee from the runDir() function.

Why is thee function below not returning a template object that I can use in my console.log stateements.

```
async function runDir() {

const template = await Template.fromDirectory('./src/acceptance-of-delivery');

return template;

};

template = runDir();

console.log("Name: " + template.getName())
console.log("From Directory Template Version: " + template.getMetadata().getVersion())
console.log("Description: " + template.getDescription())
console.log("Hash: " + template.getHash())
```

Comment: does  Template.fromDirectory returns a promise?

Comment: The `async` function returns a `Promise` that you need to `await` it or get its value from `then` callback function. Also your keyboard seems has double typing issue that you should consider to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runDir` is an async function, which its return value will be a `Promise`. So `template` here is actually a `Promise`. Try this

```js
runDir().then(template => {
  console.log("Name: " + template.getName())
  console.log("From Directory Template Version: " + template.getMetadata().getVersion())
  console.log("Description: " + template.getDescription())
  console.log("Hash: " + template.getHash())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the execution of rundir to complete , so that template gets initialized.
Async function returns a promise by default.

```
async function runDir() {

const template = await Template.fromDirectory('./src/acceptance-of-delivery');

return template;

};

template = await runDir();
// You need to wait for the execution of rundir to complete , so that template gets initialized
console.log("Name: " + template.getName())
console.log("From Directory Template Version: " + template.getMetadata().getVersion())
console.log("Description: " + template.getDescription())
console.log("Hash: " + template.getHash())
```